# Username as a path

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pathauto

I would like to have a user's name as a part of a URL, e.g. mysite.com/username. This should redirect to the user profile. I use [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto), but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pathauto, you just have to configure user paths with a user token, e.g. `[user:name]`.

Comment: What do you mean? Under section Pattern for all Profile paths I put [current-user:name]. This doesnt seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: I need a pattern for Username I guess but I dont know the correct syntax.

Comment: It says [user-raw] is invalid, all other replecment patterns do not seem to work.

Comment: I forgot, you need token module for this

Answer (score 1):

Pathauto pattern of `[user:name]` under User paths should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is that it works for user page. But I would like to do it for profile page. When I put the same pattern under Profile paths it says it is not valid.