# Username as a part of a URL

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pathauto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Username as a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961990/username-as-a-path)

I would like to create a URL such as mysite.com/user1 based on the username. If the username is "mrsmith," then the URL mysite.com/mrsmith will be automatically created and it will link to the user profile.
I was trying to do it using pathauto module in Drupal 7, but suggested patterns do not work.

Do you have any advice on how to do that?

Comment: No need to repost... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961990/user-name-as-a-path-in-drupal/5963560#5963560